# Determine if an MDI form is open

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a base form (BaseMDIForm) that several forms (Client, Inventory, Orders, etc) inherit from. On this base form is a protected string "windowID".  This id gets set by each form as a way to uniquely identify the object currently open in that form (Client.ID, Inventory.ID, Order.ID, etc).

I am successfully using this method on the Client form to find a specific client id on any open Client form:

```
// method is in the Client form (and is coded to specifically look for Client forms)
private Boolean FindFormWithWindowID(string windowID)
{
    foreach (Form form in this.MdiParent.MdiChildren)
    {
        if (form.GetType() == typeof(frmClient))
        {
            frmClient clientForm = (frmClient)form;
            if (clientForm.windowID == windowID)
            {
                // close this form because the client is open on an existing form
                if (this.windowID == "") // this won't be set yet if we're searching for an existing form
                    Close();

                form.Activate();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea behind this concept is that when a user tries to open a client record (or inventory, order, etc) that is already open on an existing form, the existing form is given the focus and brought to the front (and what would have been the newly opened form is then closed).

I'm trying to move this method to the base form so this method doesn't need to be continually created in any inherited forms, just called from those forms, as in:

```
if (!FindFormWithWindowID(ClientForm, windowID))
{
    // continue loading new form
}
```

Is there a way to pass in the form type (Client, Inventory, Orders, etc), then have this new base method loop through the existing MdiChildern of the specific passed-in form type to find a specific form that contains a given window id (keeping in mind that this method will be called from many different types of inherited forms)?  I'm trying to avoid adding a switch statement to determine the form type, as this would force me to update it anytime a completely new form is added to the project.

Comment: It is not terribly obvious why moving this method is a problem.  You probably ought to add another method to frmClient, say, static void CreateClient(string id) that does this check before you try to create a frmChild.  And, given that there is only ever one MdiParent instance, add a static method to that form that returns the one-and-only instance.

Comment: The code flow goes like this (for the client, but basically the same for all types of forms): a client form is opened, a list of clients is displayed for the user to select from. Later, after several client windows have been opened, the user decides to open a previously selected client form (forgetting it is still open).  So the new form opens, the list is shown, the user selects the client.  We now check whether that client form is already open.  So, we can't check for an open client until we open a new client form to allow the user to select a client from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WindowID doesn't actually exist on a form so I'm assuming your've got an inherited base form that you have added WindowID to.

```
public InheritedForm : Form
{
    public string WindowID { get; set; }
}
```

If this is the case then you can replace your current FindFormWithWindowID method with:

```
string windowidtolookfor = "1234";

InheritedForm foundform = Application.OpenForms.OfType<InheritedForm>().Where(f => f.WindowID = windowidtolookfor).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you want a specific type of form:

```
MyForm foundform = Application.OpenForms.OfType<MyForm>().Where(f => f.WindowID = windowidtolookfor).FirstOrDefault();
```

You will need to check that `foundform` is not null before you attempt to do anthing with it as FirstOrDefault() will return null if it cannot return a matching item.

This can be called from anywhere so you don't need to worry about picking a sensible location for it.

There seems to be a little confusion about what this is doing so I'll break it down:

`Application.OpenForms` is a property that lists all the Forms that are open within the application.

We call this then we specify the type of Form we're looking for with `OfType() this filters down the OpenForms to only those with a typeof FormX.

After this we add `Where(f => f.WindowID = "1234")`

This tells the query that we want only those forms of FormX that have a WindowID of "1234".

Finally we add `FirstOrDefault()`, this will return the first instance it finds where the Form is FormX and WindowID = "1234". If no form exists that matches the criteria then it will return NULL.

It is functionally equivalent of your FindFormWithWindowID but it allows you to change it each time you use it by substituting the OfType with whatever form type you want.

If you only want a boolean result at the end then just do it like this:

```
if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<FormX>().Where(f => f.WindowID == windowidtolookfor).FirstOrDefault() != null)
{
    // Found a window matching the criteria
}
else
{
    // Not found a window matching the criteria.
}
```

Comment: The windowID is on the base form,  so each inherited form gets that variable.  I might not be reading your examples correctly, but don't they both require the specific type of Form to be coded into the call (ie "InheritedForm" and "MyForm")?  I'm hoping to be able to pass in the type of form to look for, then search only those specific types of forms for the given windowID.    An example call from the Client window would be if (!FindFormWithWindowID(ClientForm, windowID))
{
    // continue loading new form
}

Comment: I didn't know what your base form type was so I added one called InheritedForm so that the code would make sense.

Comment: As I said, you can call this function anywhere and just replace the <MyForm> or <InheritedForm> with your form type. So if your form is of type FormWithLotsOfButtonsOn then you put OfType<FormWithLotsOfButtonsOn> instead. The beaty of this solution is that you get rid of your full method and rely on a Linq query to do the same thing. Where you'd normally call FindFormWithWindowID you'd just replace it with the linq query.

Comment: on second look, your solution will work for what I need.  Those calls will need to be added to each inherited form instead of the base.  Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Exactly, you just put that single line wherever you need to do the check rather than having to have your find method available to each of your forms.

Comment: The reason I was looking to the base to handle this is that I was going to change the windowID from a private variable into a property.  Then I could add code to the setter that would check for an existing open form.  This would then get called automatically when any form tried to set the windowID (as all forms currently do).  No new code would need to be added to the inherited forms.

Comment: You can just store your WindowID in the Tag property of the Form then you don't need a new base form class. Tag is of type object so you'd need to cast to the type you actually need in order to check it. Your WindowID should be a public property anyway for my answer to work (see the InheritedForm code at the top).

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed number of types, you could pass a string representing the type, and then check each windows type to see if it matches.

```
System.Type getTypeOfForm(string docType) {
    switch (docType) {
        case "Customer":
            return typeof(MyNameSpace.CustomerMDIForm);
        case "Invoice":
            return typeof(MyNameSpace.InvoiceMDIForm);
        case "Order":
            return typeof(MyNameSpace.OrderMDIForm);

            ...

        default:
            throw new Exception("Unknown Form Type");
    }
}
```

You can stitch the return type into your existing loop by plugging the returned runtime type in where you have '== typeof(frmClient)'. If you passed around the fully qualified class string for your target form type, you can also convert that into a System.Type object by using System.GetType(string).

You can also avoid any string to type mapping shenanigans if you simply pass a variable of System.Type to your search:

```
if (!FindFormWithWindowID(typeof(MyNameSpace.CustomerMDIForm), windowID))
```

Comment: I have a version of this currently working but I was hoping to avoid having to switch on the type of form being passed in as this would cause the code to require updating for each new form type added to the solution.  The "default" would help catch when the new form wasn't added, assuming a call was made to this method.